# Angular pattern Validator is not working as expected

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

To allow only emails with TLD (ending with .de or .com) I want to use the following pattern:

```
^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

I tested this regular expression on regexr.com a couple of times and it worked good, for example it did not match with test@test.

But the Angular Validator says no error for test@test with this pattern Validator:

```
Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$')
```

How is that possible?

Comment: try `Validators.pattern(/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash, since it's a string.

```
'^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
```